# Merging features which share geometry but not features

Tags: qgis, geometry, merge

I'm trying to create one vector layer out of two, one of which overlies the other.  I've merged the two layers but now I just have a load more polygons which share no attributes.  How do I merge the features which have the same (or overlapping) geometry while retaining the attributes of both?

Background - I want to add 'ancient woodland' and all its attributes to 'all woodland' and all its attributes.  Clearly 'ancient woodland' is a part of 'all woodland' so it always shares geometries.

[image: I want to give the layer 'NFI Exmoor' the attributes of 'Ancient Woodland Exmoor' where AWI shares geometry]

Comment: Are all "ancient woodland" features part of the "woodland" layer anyway?

Comment: I've merged them so they are now.

Comment: It's not like you still have the original data.

Comment: The geometries are exactly the same for the overlapping features? Add a screenshot

Comment: I have all the original data